# SQL Server: slow query, lots of likes

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to implement a "Broad search" functionality, which should be used to search all fields in the DB.

The parameters of the query below is all "%horse%", and the my local DB executes this in about 15 sec.

When i use the parameter "%[^A-Za-z0-9]horse[^A-Za-z0-9]%", to make "horse" an independent word. The query takes 30 + seconds.

The db contains like 3000 objects. Can the query be optimized to run in respectable time? or should i consider something like full-text index?

Comment: Please provide your execution plan and `DDL` for your tables.

Comment: while dynamic SQL is a pain and can be dangerous, sometimes it is better to build the query string with just the options selected, then execute it rather than a lot of or statements

Comment: also check out this article on a bunch of different options. http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: thank you both, as you might suspect im a rookie. Didn't even know about DDL and execution plan - i will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using DISTINCT indicates you may have a flawed data model.
2. Checking for NULL seems redundant.
3. Adding space to all column values is a terrible idea which will slow down your query because it is not [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable):

Try this syntax(for all columns) in the WHERE clause instead

```
(tblCollection.CollectionID like '%[^A-Za-z0-9]horse[^A-Za-z0-9]%' escape '\' or
tblCollection.CollectionID like 'horse[^A-Za-z0-9]%' escape '\' or
tblCollection.CollectionID like '[^A-Za-z0-9]horse' escape '\')
```

Comment: Thank you! 2. and 3. reduced time from >30sec to about 15 sec. 
Can you explain why you would check for all 3 cases in your example? wouldt just the first be sufficient?

Comment: it wpuld not select rows with columns starting or ending with horse if you exclude the last 2